# Integrate swagger 1.2 with node js/Angular frontend

Tags: swagger

I have a backend application which produces api docs with swagger version 1.2. The front end of my application is node with angular js. Please let me know how to provide a link to api docs (generated from backend app) from node js. Most of the npm modules, I tried were supporting only swagger 2.0 and not 1.2